# Can you prevent iPhone from using native select menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iphone, twitter-bootstrap

I have a select menu that has some very long options in it. When viewing the form on the iPhone it uses the native select menu, which cuts off the text of each option. Is there a way to prevent the iPhone from using the native select menu?

I looked into jQuery mobile, but I've built the site on Bootstrap, and they don't play well together. I tried just implementing the form portion of jQuery mobile, but it still caused all sorts of conflicts, so I abandoned that path.

Is there a solution for this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: See if this works: http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/3/

Comment: You won't be able to disable the native behavior/look. Instead create the dropdown using a CSS Framework such as bootstrap, foundation or jQuery Mobile or UI since you're already use this JS library.

Comment: @Christina, sorry I missed this comment. That bootstrap-select script works, too. Thanks!

Comment: that link is:  http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution with a script that replaces a select with a ul list, this is what I use.

`Fiddle:` http://jsfiddle.net/futgfs10/2/

Comment: Awesome! That'll be perfect. Thanks very much.